# HttpClient - how to set fingerprint and _csrf?

Tags: java, httpclient, token, csrf

I have used HttpClient a couple of times. 
But the current website i want to handle wants 4 parameter in the httpPost request: loginName , password, _csrf , fingerprint

I dont know where i can find or generate a _csrf and fingerprint.
I recorded a login with Firefox LiveHttp-Header-Addon and the data has to look like: 
loginMail=myEmail@gmx.de&password=myPassword&_csrf=f16e2835-492b-4703-ba21-c11e58cf1088&fingerprint=94311eb7ec0497339794b1024f05e0a9

My current code looks like:

```
HttpPost login = new HttpPost("https://www.Webseite.de/einloggen.html");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginMail", "login_name"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "login_passwort"));
login.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(login);
```

So the question is, where i can get the fingerprint and _csrf?

Answer (score 0):

I found the _csrf token in the .html code of the website.

So first i send a HttpGet and  then i save the response into a String and search for the keyword.

Where i can found the fingerprint? Is this parameter realy needed?